# Shuffling Voice Memos

Tags: iphone, playlist, voice-memo

I've created a playlist of a selection of Voice Memos.  I want to use it as a kind of audio flash card system.  However, when I press "Shuffle" on the iPhone playlist, it always plays the same voice memo and it never plays more than one.  I want it to play all of them in a random order.  Is this possible?  If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on the same issue and I just found something that worked.

Once you've created your playlist of voice memos and converted them into the AAC format, then sync your iphone/ipod.

To listen to the voice memo's in shuffle: go into your music app and click artists. All your voice memo's will be under one artist and click shuffle.